# Edit background color of widget in palette editor of QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, background-color

I would like to change the background color of a QWidget in the graphical designer of QT Creator. I know how to do it programmatically and know how to edit all other colors, like the ones for text, etc. But the color palette editor doesn't seem to have an option for background color. Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

PS: I searched a lot but of course only ended up with coded solutions, but I'd like to avoid as much coding as possible for the view setup.

[image: NO background color option here]

Comment: I somehow managed to do it in the way that you are trying to. But I think that the preview doesn't work properly.

Comment: Okay it works - I once tried auto fill but apparently with the wrong roles and now that I set all the roles to bright green and auto fill to true it did the job. Thanks! The role you need to set is called Window. Do you think I should answer the question or delete it? Not many people seem to be interested.

Comment: Answering your own question is the best option here. And I think you can also mark your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ni1ight I found out that you have to set the Window-role color to the desired color in the color palette editor and also check autofill background color.

Answer (score 6):

First : Click on StyleSheet

[image: Click]

Then click on add color and choose your background color or whatever

[image]

Comment: you are welcome, it's a good practice. I prefer to do it this way instead of writing tedious line sof code :)

Comment: Definitely! :) Although I like the solution that @ni1ight pointed out even more, because you can use the graphical color editor ;)